# Ansible loop sequentially with_nested multiple array

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I want to use with_nested but with 2 different array sequentially,

devices:

- data: /dev/vdb
- data: /dev/vdc

hostname:

- host1
- host2
- host3

I was trying use this way

```
- name: debug
  debug: msg="{{ item[0] }} {{ item[1] }}"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ devices }}"
    - "{{ hostname }}"
```

But the result like this :

```
- /dev/vdb host1
- /dev/vdb host2
- /dev/vdb host3
- /dev/vdc host1
- /dev/vdc host2
- /dev/vdc host3
```

I expected result like this:

```
- /dev/vdb host1
- /dev/vdc host1
- /dev/vdb host2
- /dev/vdc host2
- /dev/vdb host3
- /dev/vdc host3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a nested look, equivalent to:

for item0 in devices:
for item1 in hostname:
print(item0, item1)

For each item in `devices`, it will iterate over all the items in `hostname`...giving exactly the results you've described. You're still getting the same list of pairs that you expect, just in a different order.

If you reverse the arguments to `with_nested`, like this:

```
    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item[0] }} {{ item[1] }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ hostname }}"
        - "{{ devices }}"
```

You'll get the pairs in the order you want, albeit swapped:

```
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['host1', '/dev/vdb']) => {
    "msg": "host1 /dev/vdb"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['host1', '/dev/vdc']) => {
    "msg": "host1 /dev/vdc"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['host2', '/dev/vdb']) => {
    "msg": "host2 /dev/vdb"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['host2', '/dev/vdc']) => {
    "msg": "host2 /dev/vdc"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['host3', '/dev/vdb']) => {
    "msg": "host3 /dev/vdb"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['host3', '/dev/vdc']) => {
    "msg": "host3 /dev/vdc"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```